# Eth0 missing on Linux 3.18.8 with onboard Realtek card

Tags: linux, networking

Ethernet is completely gone on a Laptop with Linux Mint Cinnamon 64 and Kernel 3.18.8. I have installed the realtek driver from their website, but that is not solving the issue.

`ifconfig -a` only lists `lo`, `wlan0` and not that controller as `eth0` or something similar.

`sudo lspci -v` shows that no kernel module is in use:

```
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
Subsystem: Lenovo Device 5028
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 7
I/O ports at 3000 [size=256]
Memory at f1d04000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
Memory at f1d00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 01
Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable- Count=4 Masked-
Capabilities: [d0] Vital Product Data
Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
Capabilities: [140] Virtual Channel
Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number {removed for post}
Capabilities: [170] Latency Tolerance Reporting
Capabilities: [178] L1 PM Substates
```

finally `sudo lshw -numeric -C network` gives me:

```
 *-network UNCLAIMED     
   description: Ethernet controller
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10EC:8168]
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. [10EC]
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
   version: 10
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: ioport:3000(size=256) memory:f1d04000-f1d04fff memory:f1d00000-f1d03fff
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing the Debian package for the Ethernet card solves the issue. http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/r/r8168/

That said, it *should* not be necessary to install the Debian package, as the Kernel should provide for the Ethernet card already. However it did not work without. After installing Kernel 4.0 i had the same issue again.